# Find words before and after a matched keyword between two Pandas Dataframe columns and return in new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to find the first three words before and after a string between two dataframe columns and return in two new columns named 'Words Before' and 'Words after'.

my dataframe

```
Keyword          Description
pet              cat car dog pet day bye are
```

my desired output

```
Keyword         Description                         Words Before          Words After     
pet             cat car dog pet day bye are         cat car dog           day bye are
```

what I've tried
The closet I've come is being able to manually search for a word and return the word prior, but it's not what I need.

```
df['Words Before'], df['Words After'] = df['Description'].str.extract(r"(\w+Keyword)"), df['Description'].str.extract(r"(\w+Keyword)")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit: Test Dataframe

```
data = {'keyword': ['pet'], 'description': ["cat car dog pet day bye are"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use assert lookahead that is k(?=l); k only if followed by l and also assert positive lookbehind, that is (?<=e)f; f only if e comes before it. Code bellow

```
df=df.assign(WordsBefore=df.Description.str.extract('(^\D+(?=pet))'),
WordsAfter=df.Description.str.extract('((?<=pet)\D+)'))
print(df)
```

If you want to call the keyword right from dataframe, use f string;
Code below

```
s=df.Keyword
df=df.assign(WordsBefore=df.Description.str.extract("(^\D+(?=f'{s}'))"),
WordsAfter=df.Description.str.extract("((?<=f'{s}')\D+)"))
print(df)



    Keyword      Description            WordsBefore    WordsAfter
0     pet  cat car dog pet day bye are  cat car dog    day bye are
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this. I an't seem to make it work with the f-string. The first code works fine, but I nothing extracts when I use an fstring to do it. Any help appreciated!

Comment: data = {'keyword': ['pet'], 'description': ["cat car dog pet day bye are"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Words Before'], df['Words After'] = df['Description'].str.split('your_keyword')
```

this would give you two separate lists, which you could convert to strings after

if you need to find out the 4th word then first split the words by a ' ' delimiter:

```
third_word = df['Description'].str.split(' ')[3]
```